# How to update the client.pem in nodes while chef server migration from old to new?

Tags: chef-infra

I successfully migrated open source chef-11 to open source chef-12 server using knife-backup. However, knife-backup does not seem to update the nodes, and all my nodes are still pointing to the old server in their respective client.rb files, and their validation.pem and client.pem are still paired with the old server.

Obviously, one way to do so would be to bootstrap the node again to the new server, however I do not want to do that because I do not want to deploy to these nodes because that could cause a loss of data.

Is there any way to update client.pem in the nodes without having to bootstrap the client node.

I have followed this link to migrate:

https://docs.chef.io/release/osc_11-1/upgrade_server_open_source.html

Comment: Doesn't the "knife backup" plugin restore the client entries onto the new chef server? That will contain the public key associated with each node. Sounds to me what you need to do is update each client.rb file on each server and update the "chef_server_url" setting. You might also need to disable SSL verification which is mandatory in Chef 12.

Answer (score 0):

The key isn't what you have to update, that should be fine from the backup and restore. What determines the server to talk to is the `client.rb` config file on each server. You'll have to update those somehow. `knife ssh '*:*' sed ....` would probably be enough.